# constructor Handler()' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Tags: android, kotlin

Необходим вызов функции проверки координат, для этого я использую
функцию `touch`, которая с помощью `Handler()` вызывает раз в пол секунды функцию проверки координат и при касании экрана раскрашивает квадратики (меняет цвет `imageView`, при касании по координатам расположения этого элемента).
При сборке выдается предупреждение

> constructor Handler()' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java.

Я заменил на более новую версию `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed`, но теперь не работает эта часть кода, при касании квадратики не раскрашиваются, то есть функция не вызывается

```kotlin
private fun touch () {
    val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            checkCoordinates () // функция проверки координат и раскрашивания квадратиков
            mX = 0.0f
            mY = 0.0f
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500)
        }
    }, 0)
}
```

Заменено на:

```kotlin
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        fun run() {
            checkCoordinates()
            mX = 0.0f
            mY = 0.0f
        }
    }, 500)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно было просто добавить аргумент в конструктор, а вы полностью изменили код и теперь вызов не периодический, а отложенный одноразовый. Верните как было:

```
private fun touch () {
    val handler = Handler(Looper.myLooper())
    handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            checkCoordinates () // функция проверки координат и раскрашивания квадратиков
            mX = 0.0f
            mY = 0.0f
            handler.postDelayed(this, 500)
        }
    }, 0)
}
```

**P.S.** устаревший конструктор без параметров равносилен конструктору с аргументом `Looper.myLooper()` - это означает что хандлер будет выполнять код в том потоке, в котором он создан.

`Looper.getMainLooper()` - означает что хандлер будет выполнять код в главном (UI) потоке.

Comment: спасибо, получилось как надо, изменив на `val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`